# How to show Nirvana Tikku, radial menu at any position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, radial

I am Not Familiar with JavaScript and i am beginner in jQuery!  I Found [RadMenu Pluging](http://tikku.com/jquery-radmenu-plugin) from web and want to use it so that the it opens anywhere on document where I click, not just one fixed position.

```
$(function() {
        jQuery("#radial_container").radmenu({
            listClass: 'list',
            itemClass: 'item',
            radius: 100,
            animSpeed: 400,
            centerX: 30,
            centerY: 100,
            selectEvent: "click",
            onSelect: function($selected) {
                alert("you clicked on .. "
                + $selected.index());
            },
            angleOffset: Math.PI,
            onShow: function($menuitems) {
                $menuitems.each(function(i) {
                    var $this = jQuery(this);
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $this.fadeIn(500);
                    }, i * 100);
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

I am trying to update the centerX and centerY values in in real time with onClick or with mouseover methods , but its not getting updated.

Please suggest me what to do to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished by changing the `top` and `left` properties of the `<div>` containing your radial menu, when the click event happens. For example,

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
  $('#radial_container').css('left', (e.pageX - 30) + 'px');
  $('#radial_container').css('top', (e.pageY - 40) + 'px');
  $("#radial_container").radmenu("show");
});
```

Here is a fiddle with a working version that you can play with further: http://jsfiddle.net/munderwood/7asLq/

The two values `-30` and `-40` that I use to shift the centre of the circle were picked just because they appear to work, more or less. They will change with the radius of the menu, text size, and so on, but I left them in so that you would see how and where to shift the menu relative to the mouse cursor.

Comment: Thank you very very much. works like charm. :) I have less reputation points  to vote up your solution :( but thanks for answer. I was trying wrong method all way long !!
Here is my current work with your help :)
http://ajitsonlion.com/work/main/

Can you give me some pointers on how to make it touch optimized.
the click and mouseover events dont translate  very well on touchscreen.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have much experience writing JS for mobile. One good option might be to use the click event, and not make the menu disappear as soon as you lift up. That way the user can open the menu, and then look at it without their finger in the way, before choosing which submenu to open. Another option is to find a way to respond to tap events. A quick Google search found this page that looks helpful: http://www.gianlucaguarini.com/blog/detecting-the-tap-event-on-a-mobile-touch-device-using-javascript. Alternatively, you could ask another question here.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try that. Hope can make it work.
Thanks :)